# NSTimer crashes iphone simulator on second run

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator, nstimer

The following applicationWillTerminate saves the state of started, stopped, startTime and stopTime and invalidates the timer.  The intent is to be able to terminate application then restore state and restart timer on app restart.

```
//Save status to file on applicationWillTerminate.
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
NSMutableArray *status = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[status addObject:startTime];
[status addObject:stopTime];
[status addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger: started]];
[status addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger: stopped]];
[status writeToFile:[self statusFilePath] atomically:YES];
[status release];
if ([timer isValid]) {
    [timer invalidate];
}
[lblTimer release];
[txtDescription release];
[lblDriverName release];
[startTime release];
[stopTime release];
//  [timer release];
//  timer = nil;
}
```

The following viewDidLoad restores the state and is supposed to restart the timer when the if condition is met.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
// Re-direct applicationWillTerminate.
UIApplication *driverApp = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
    selector:@selector(applicationWillTerminate:) 
    name:UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification 
    object:driverApp];
// Initialize status for first run, over-ride for saved status.
NSString *statusPath = [self statusFilePath];
BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:statusPath];
if (fileExists) {
    // Over-ride for status saved.
    NSArray *values = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:statusPath];
    startTime = [values objectAtIndex:0];
    stopTime = [values objectAtIndex:1];
    started = [[values objectAtIndex:2] intValue];
    stopped = [[values objectAtIndex:3] intValue];
    [values release];
}
else {
    // For first run.
    started = 0;
    stopped = 0;
}
// Restart timer if previously still running.
if (started == 1 && stopped == 0) {
    if (![timer isValid]) {
        timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.25
            target:self
            selector:@selector(updateTimer)
            userInfo:nil
            repeats:YES];
    }   
}
[super viewDidLoad];
}
```

The program runs ok in the simulator the first time.  On the second simulator run, the app crashes when it reaches the timer = [NSTimer.............repeats:YES]; statement.  I have researched and tried numerous things to no avail.

Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: have you initialized timer anywhere? If you can isValid on a nil object, I guess it would give you an exception?

Comment: Other portions of the code initialize and invalidate the timer.  Those portions of code will run properly for as many times as they are invoked.  I don't have the problem until I press the simulator home button the terminate the app then restart by selecting the app icon on the simulator.

Comment: I would add that on the second run the simulator displays the xib momentarily then flashes back to the iphone app screen.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (![timer isValid]) {
```

Change to:

```
if (nil == timer) {
```

Comment: I tied your suggestion, but I got the same behavior.  I went a step farther and in applicationWillTerminate changed

 if (![timer isValid]) {
to
if (!(nil == timer)) {

and still got the same behavior.

Comment: Correction.  Changed
if (![timer isValid]) to if (nil == timer)